# Allow access to certain locations via IP whitelist only in NGINX

Tags: wordpress, nginx, subdomain, multisite

I am using [Sucuri Scanner](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sucuri-scanner/) to notify me of failed login attempts and I am currently getting about 50+ emails a day. I've tried several different ways to block access to **wp-login.php** and **wp-admin** without any luck, because I think these rules possibly don't work with subdomains (or generally just suck).

```
server {
    # Primary domain, secondary domain and subdomains are explicitly 
    # declared so that I can generate certs using CertBot
    server_name primarydomain.com
                secondarydomain.com
                subdomain1.primarydomain.com
                subdomain2.primarydomain.com
                subdomain3.primarydomain.com;

    client_max_body_size 20M;
    root /home/username/www/primarydomain.com/public_html;
    index index.php;
    error_log /home/username/www/primarydomain.com/logs/error.log error;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
    }

    # This doesn't seem to block access
    location /wp-login.php {
        allow XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;    # this is my ipaddress
        deny all;
    }

    # This doesn't seem to block access    
    location /wp-admin/ {
        deny all;
        allow XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;    # this is my ipaddress
    }

    # This doesn't seem to block access
    location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login\.php) {
        deny all;
        allow XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;    # this is my ipaddress
    }
}
```

Comment: Blocking `wp-admin/` will break your site Ajax, which uses `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`

Comment: @RRikesh I only want to block IPs which do not belong to me. I've successfully done it via Apache .htaccess on another server.

Answer (score 10):

It's not working because `regexps` have *higher* priority than prefixes in `nginx`

https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

> To find location matching a given request, nginx first checks
>   locations defined using the prefix strings (prefix locations). Among
>   them, the location with the longest matching prefix is selected and
>   remembered.

And here's the point:

> Then regular expressions are checked, in the order of their appearance
>   in the configuration file. The search of regular expressions
>   terminates on the first match, and the corresponding configuration is
>   used. If no match with a regular expression is found then the
>   configuration of the prefix location remembered earlier is used

So this expression would handle all the requests

```
location ~ \.php$
```

One of the solutions might be to transform your `prefix` locations into regexps and move them upwards in the config files

Or use `=` modifier for urls you'd like to restrict access to

> Also, using the “=” modifier it is possible to define an exact match
>   of URI and location. If an exact match is found, the search terminates

More examples from the docs:

```
location = / {
    [ configuration A ]
}

location / {
    [ configuration B ]
}

location /documents/ {
    [ configuration C ]
}

location ^~ /images/ {
    [ configuration D ]
}

location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ {
    [ configuration E ]
}
```

> The “/” request will match configuration A, the “/index.html” request
>   will match configuration B, the “/documents/document.html” request
>   will match configuration C, the “/images/1.gif” request will match
>   configuration D, and the “/documents/1.jpg” request will match
>   configuration E

Answer (score 3):

Do try [iTheme security plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/) with custom login URL and [google recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/) plugin. It reduces the attack up to an extent. A month ago we were getting so many attacks on our site but now it's fine, it got reduced to 2 /week to none.

Comment: Please don't link to your website unless absolutely necessary. It might be perceived as spam.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest fix would be to use nested location

```
http{
server {

        server_name *.domain.com;
        listen 80;

        location ~ \.php$ {
           location ~ /wp-login\.php$ {
                deny all;
           }
           location ~ ^/wp-admin/ {
                deny all;
           }
           return 200 "OK";
        }
}
```

And the test results are as below

```
$ curl vm/testing.php
OK%                                                                                                                                                                                         

$ curl vm/wp-login.php
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty/1.11.2.2</center>
</body>
</html>

 $ curl vm/wp-admin/index.php
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty/1.11.2.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```